# Django 1.4 on App engine works with ndb but not db after upgrade to HRD

Tags: django, google-app-engine, python-2.7

Trace from local server:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pk/Desktop/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 266, in Handle
    result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
  File "/Users/pk/Desktop/Lkos_hrd/los/src/common/zip-packages/django.zip/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 219, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/Users/pk/Desktop/Lkos_hrd/los/src/common/zip-packages/django.zip/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 45, in load_middleware
    mod = import_module(mw_module)
  File "/Users/pk/Desktop/Lkos_hrd/los/src/common/zip-packages/django.zip/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/pk/Desktop/Lkos_hrd/los/src/website/middleware.py", line 1, in <module>
    from website.models import Preference, Person
  File "/Users/pk/Desktop/Lkos_hrd/los/src/website/models.py", line 7, in <module>
    from logic.persongroup import *
  File "/Users/pk/Desktop/Lkos_hrd/los/src/logic/persongroup.py", line 10, in <module>
    class PersonGroup(db.Model):
  File "/Users/pk/Desktop/Lkos_hrd/los/src/common/appenginepatch/appenginepatcher/patch.py", line 549, in __init__
    signals.class_prepared.send(sender=cls)
  File "/Users/pk/Desktop/Lkos_hrd/los/src/common/zip-packages/django.zip/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 172, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/Users/pk/Desktop/Lkos_hrd/los/src/common/zip-packages/django.zip/django/db/models/manager.py", line 36, in ensure_default_manager
    for base_class in default_mgr.mro()[1:]:
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    descriptor 'mro' of 'type' object needs an argument
```

Upgraded to Google app engine High Res and python 2.7 and ran into this problem. As a test, I changed from 'google.appengine.ext import db' to 'from google.appengine.ext import ndb' and also updated e.g. class person(db.model) to class person(ndb.model)

Then the damn thing began to move past this error but I'd have to change every model and property to move to ndb to make the whole thing work. It's as if it does not recognise the old db API at all, so I'm guessing I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You'll pretty much be on your own trying to get Google App Engine Launcher + Django 1.4 working.  Development has moved on to Django-nonrel for the HRD.

https://django-nonrel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: I am currently using app-engine patch as I'm happy to use the GAE models rather than django models. I thought the error suggested that I'm missing a setting rather than a wholesale change. Also, it would be odd that ndb worked and db did not.

Comment: I believe app-engine patch monkey-patches db.models to provide some extra functionality (I think for forms).  I'm assuming that breaks with Django 1.4.  ndb is untouched so it loads up fine.

Comment: that makes sense to me. It's a struggle finding anyone with the exact same migration problems and app engine patch is not being updated. I might just try sticking to an older version of django that works with patch

Comment: Yep, went back to 1.1 version of django and er.. so far, so good.